# jQuery $('parent > *') selector & iOS with a click delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <span class="stuff">Content</span>
  <span class="stuff">Content</span>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).delegate("#wrapper > *","click", function(){
  //do stuff
}
```

Above is a short code break out of my structure.

Basically I am trying to provide an click event for the parent and all children.

This seems to work fine in Safari, Chrome, Firefox,  and IE 7+.  However it doesn't seem to on iOS devices (have not tested android).

Anyone have any idea how to get this to work, or a better approach?

Comment: Why not just `$(document).delegate("#wrapper","click", function(){...}` ?

Comment: because im then grabbing a bit later.  $(this).parent('#wrapper').children('.stuff').html();  My understanding or lack there of is just doing #wrapper will cause possible issues with other elements inside the div and event bubbling if not clicked directly on an area thats #wrapper?

Comment: Can you make a JsFiddle example, and maybe a little description of what's not working on iOS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r3E6a/  Whats not working is the event itself does not fire.  I'm assuming it's something to do with the selector, but at this point I'm just shrugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your iOS device: http://jsfiddle.net/r3E6a/1/show

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/r3E6a/1/

Cheers.

Comment: Nice seems to work.  Thank you very much.  So appears the delegate is the culprit, doing it from the outer div rather then document.

Comment: Well, no. I think maybe you're a little confused about how delegate works. Essentially, you define a parent element (or elements) which listen for events to bubble up from their child elements. When the event bubbles up to the parent, it checks to see if that element matches the selector you passed as the first argument to `delegate()`. If it does, the callback gets executed.

Comment: Well after trying to apply it to full code this still didn't work.  The #listings in this case get pulled in via ajax, so I still dont think the event is propagating correctly on iOS.

Comment: Okay. Try changing the selector to the parent of the #listings element (or whatever its closest parent is that will exist on page load).